# wordpress pre_get_posts hide by value that contains string

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am trying to hide a bunch of WooCommerce products from the frontend that contains the string "-FOC" in the sku. Here are a few things i have tried:

**Option 1 Unsuccessful**

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query_1' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query_1( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

$meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'=>'_sku',
    'value' => '-FOC',
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
$q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query_1' );

}
```

**Option 2 Unsuccessful**

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query_1' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query_1( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

$meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'=>'_sku',
    'value' => '[FOC$]',
    'compare'=>'REGEX',

    );
$q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query_1' );

}
```

According to the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) there is no compare option for "CONTAINS". Is this right?

Is there an alteranitve around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT LIKE` compare option. So to hide the product from the product list, you can do it like this:

```php
function custom_pre_get_posts_query_1( $q, $instance ) {
    $meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'=>'_sku',
        'value' => '-FOC',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
    );
    $q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
};


add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query_1', 10, 2 );
```

But it can still be access if you have the direct link to that product